# MsSql server 2008 r2 Data Syncronization

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, data-synchronization

I'm working on a project in C#.NET (WPF) with 2 SQL Server 2008 R2 databases. I need to update new/changed data from local db to online db. Client system has low bandwidth connection. So I need a solution to upload a file to sync.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Programming example will be more beneficial for me.

Comment: What approaches have you thought about or tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about the following:

- [SQL Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

  - Supports unidirectional or bidirectional synchronization
- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)

  - Lets you define the mappings of the data, as well as transformations, and attach other code to the process easily
- [Linked-servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

  - Allows you to query databases and tables on remote servers as though they are part of the local database.  Very easy to setup (just call `exec sp_addlinkedserver`) and once defined uses nothing but plain old SQL

  [Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) is a simple tutorial about how to create a linked server.
  After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

  ```
  select * from [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[schema].[TableName]
  ```

If you need this to occur on a button-click or so, then I'd suggest you use linked servers within a stored procedure--they're the simplest option.  SSIS would also be suitable, you'd need to execute the package on the button-click.